# Empty anchor tag value using hash or javascript in Angular

Tags: angularjs

We're trying to come up to speed with Angular.js and our lead JS dev has requested that when we mock up links that don't yet have a page to go to, we should do the following:

```
<a href="javascript://">
```

instead of this:

```
<a href="#">
```

His reasoning was that Angular already has a use for the hash tag because it means something to Angular and if it doesn't find the router/directive then it is redirected to /scenario.

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you just not set an `href` at all, and use CSS to style them the same?

Comment: @OverZealous I read elsewhere that this is possibly a good way to go. Either not include `href` or just include `href` with no value. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [AngularJS docs for the A directive](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:a), you should be using `href=""`.

> The reasoning for this is to allow easy creation of action links with ngClick directive without changing the location or causing page reloads, e.g.: `<a href="" ng-click="model.$save()">Save</a>`